# Flatten a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am solving a ODE as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import math
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(y, x):
    y0 = y[0]
    return x   #formula##

# Initial conditions on y, y' at x=0
init = 0   #value##
# First integrate from 0 to 100
xplotval=np.linspace(4,8,4)  #linspacefunction
print(xplotval)
```

I am getting output as:

```
[[ 7.         ]
 [ 5.76455273 ]
 [ 5.41898906 ]
 [ 6.49185668 ]]
```

I'd like to output a single dimensional array as follows:

```
[7., 5.76455273, 5.41898906, 6.49185668]
```

How can I?

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots. Just copypaste your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
print(xplotval.flatten())
```

Unless you actually want the *transposed vector*, which you would get with [`numpy.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
print(np.transpose(xplotval))
```

Comment: No it is not working as I needed. I need as array. It not makes array!!

Comment: the elements are not comma seperated. I am getting output as `[7.  5.76455273 5.41898906  6.49185668]`. I want it as comma seperated

Comment: You can output any array separated by commas with `string.join(array, ",")`. In your case `print(string.join([str(x) for x in np.transpose(xplotval)], ", "))` should work.

Comment: what you mean by `string`? I get as undefined variable

Comment: You have to [`import string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) first, of course.

Comment: @ Tobia Tesan Error     `print(string.join([str(x) for x in np.transpose(xplotval)], ", "))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89604/discussion-between-user1989-and-tobia-tesan).

Comment: If you are using Python 3 (which you didn't mention), you want `print(','.join([str(x) for x in np.transpose(xplotval)]))` (which is perfectly good in Python 2 as well and probably cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use list comprehension, something like:

```
oneD = [l[0] for l in xplotval]
```